# Facing an issue with CakePHP and HTML2PDF

Tags: php, cakephp, html2pdf

I'm developping a web site using CakePHP, and in some pages, I use HTML2PDF that is a plugins whose name explains well what it does. Since now it worked well but I'm facing a strange issue. In one of the pages that I want to convert, I use PHP to send informations from my controller to the HTML code.

IN MY PAGE :

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="padding:10px;">
        <b>Personne responsable de la fin de vie : <?php echo   $People[0]['FirstName']." ".$People[0]['Name'];?></b>
    </td>
</tr>
```

IN THE CONTROLLER

```
$People= $this->Equipement->getPeople($Equipement['Id']);

if (count($People)==0){
            $People[0]['Name'] = 'Example';
            $People[0]['FirstName'] = 'Example';
        }
```

When $People is fill with informations from the database, that are basically just a name and a firstname, it doesn't work (Error 3). But when it passes through the "if" and "reset" to example, it works ! I don't understand why it does that. 
Thank you for your help and your time.

Comment: you use 'name' and 'firstName' as index in the controller but in the view you use 'Prenom' and 'Nom', why? Also remember to post your full error message so that people can better understand your problem

Comment: Oh it's just because i've changed it in the controller just for peaople to understand here because it is in french and I forgot to change it in the view too. and this is all the error shows : **error: 3
file: C:\INRA_ST\INRA_ST\app\webroot\theme\plugins\html2pdf\_class\parsingHtml.class.php
line: 102

######

HTML : .../div> </page>...**